# Google cloud storage delete only own objects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket where multiple service accounts can upload their objects so they have storage.objects.create, and ACL set to projectPrivate. But I want them to be able to overwrite(delete) only the objects they uploaded, so they don't overwrite other peoples objects. All objects need to be readable by everyone. But if I give them storage.objects.delete, they can overwrite any objects in this bucket.

Can I set some permission so they can delete only items they are creators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#bestpractices):

> to **overwrite** an object, the person performing the overwrite (and is
>   gaining ownership of the object by doing so) must have WRITER or OWNER
>   permission on the **bucket** in which the object is being uploaded.

Since, having the **writer** or **owner** permission on the bucket will grant access to other files within the bucket, I'm afraid that what you're asking is not possible.

However, you can use different buckets for different service accounts.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the documentation found here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#predefined-acl

We find that the ACL `projectPrivate` gives the user/serviceAccount permissions based on their role.  However, there is an alternate ACL called `private` that is documented as:

> Gives the bucket or object owner OWNER permission for a bucket or
>   object, and removes all other access permissions.

If I am reading this correctly, it sounds like what you want.  Especially the concept that it removes all other access permissions which I take to mean that it removes all other access permissions for OTHER users.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question: All objects need to be readable by everyone.

Comment: For example: My bucket is fine-grained, my object has only "User - my user - Owner" and using a service account that has "storage.objects.delete"  i'm able to delete that object.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question. I think this will help you. 

There is something called **Default object ACLs**

> By default, anyone who has OWNER permission or WRITER permission on a
>   bucket can upload objects into that bucket. When you upload an object,
>   you can provide a predefined ACL or not specify an ACL at all.  If you
>   don't specify an ACL, Cloud Storage applies the bucket's default
>   object ACL to the object. **Every bucket has a default object ACL**,
>   and this ACL is applied to all objects uploaded to that bucket without
>   a predefined ACL or an ACL specified in the request (JSON API only).
>   The initial value for the default object ACL of every bucket is
>   projectPrivate.

Based on how objects are uploaded, object ACLs are applied accordingly:

**Authenticated Uploads**

If you make an authenticated request to upload an object and do not specify any object ACLs when you upload it, then you are listed as the owner of the object and the predefined projectPrivate ACL is applied to the object by default. This means:

- You (the person who uploaded the object) are listed as the object
  owner. Object ownership cannot be changed by modifying ACLs. You can
  change object ownership only by overwriting an object.
- You (the object owner) are granted OWNER permission on the object. If
  you attempt to give less than OWNER permission to the owner, Cloud
  Storage automatically escalates the permission to OWNER.
- The project owners and project editors group have OWNER permission on
  the object.
- The project team members group has READER permission on the object.

   
  Source and for more information : [Click here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists)

Comment: This even solves your problem I guess, all object will be readable by everyone. 
You got to dig this more for the proper implementation. But I am pretty much sure, this solves your problem.